# Why is some text size in the browser appear bigger while viewing on a moblie device?

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I just made a site for a bbq site and when you view the old75.com/home/contact/ page on a iphone, you will see that the content appears normal as the footer is in a more larger font. But the font size of the footer is the same as the content. Can anyone see why this could be? I have this problem on some other sites as well.

Comment: I checked your site,l and the footer text size seems to match the regular font size of the rest of the site, sans the 'Call Ahead' text.  Can you clarify what is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try explicitly setting a font-size on your body.  When I'm coding up a template, I always set the default font-size I want on the body and then override as needed.

```
body {
   font-size: 1em;
}
```

This way I know that the browser isn't defaulting anything to what it thinks the font size should be.  It also means that if you want to quickly boost/shrink the font-size later, you only have to change it in one spot.